# Regex for followed by special characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want the regex for the following word pattern. The pattern starts with open brace,dollar(`{$`) and followed by any special character and ends with closing brace(`}`)

```
eg:  {$!#%^$#}
```

I tired the following   `$regex = '/(^\\{\\$[^a-zA-Z])).*?(\\})/i';`

But have no luck.

Please help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need double escaping here and you can use `\W` (non word character) for your regex:

```
$regex = '/^\{\$\W*\}/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the problem is you have an unbalanced  bracket in your regex.

```
$regex = '/(^\\{\\$[^a-zA-Z])).*?(\\})/i';
                             ^ remove this one
```

As per your question's description, I'll suggest you to use:

```
$regex = '/(^\\{\\$.*?\\})/i';
```